# Joomla/PHP - pass results (array) from model into view and show it

Tags: php, joomla

I'm experimenting with creating my own joomla component. Component searches records in database tables. but I have a problem with how to show them.

I have a search form that sends the search phrase to the module.

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <input name="company" id="form_hladat" maxlength="150" class="inputbox search-query input-medium" type="search" placeholder="hladat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="basic" />
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_regne" />
</form>
```

In the `basic` module I have a search function.

```
public function search() {
    $badchars = array('#', '>', '<', '\\');
    $searchword = trim(str_replace($badchars, '', $this->input->getString('company', null, 'post')));

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();       
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('cin','name')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('corporates'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('cin') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($searchword) . ' OR ' . $db->quoteName('name') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%'.$searchword.'%'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $results = $rows;

    return $this->results;
}
```

I do not know how to call the function/results from `view.html.php` and then how do I get the result to show in `default.php`

does anyone please tell me how to go? I'm already desperate.

Comment: You have to use Controller.

Comment: I tried it, but I totally entangled in it. I came across the same problem. I do not know call array/results from controller to view and default.php.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014548/how-to-pass-variable-from-controller-to-the-view-joomla-mvc

Comment: this solution does not take 'modul' in 'basic' view. the use of 'setRedirect' is probably better $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_regne&view=basic', false));